# Jetpack Compose: Two Buttons in with same height a Row

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to place two buttons in a Row, the height of the first button is adaptive, and the height of the second button is consistent with the first button. In my implementation code below, everything is normal when the text of the first button exceeds one line, but when there is only one line, the heights of the two buttons are inconsistent.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun IntrinsicTest() {
    Row (Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)){
        Button(
            onClick = {}) {
            Text("button\n1") // It's fine

            // Text("button1") // It's not ok

        }

        Button(
            onClick={},
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            Text("button2")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: When first button's text exceeds one line]

[image: The first button has only one line of text]

Comment: Why do you have `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` for second button?

Comment: @Abhimanyu If the second button does not have Modifier.fillMaxHeight(), its height is independent of the height of the first button. My original need was to be highly consistent

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add fillMaxHeight() in first Button()!

Your updated code:

```
@Composable
fun IntrinsicTest() {
    Row (Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)){
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            //Text("button\n1\n3\n5") // It's fine

             Text("button1") // It's not ok

        }

        Button(
            onClick={},
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            Text("button2")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is possible, but it will result in the height of buttons not being compact enough